# My Python game isn't checking if enemy is dead

Tags: python, python-3.x

I don't see why this game isn't working. Whenever the health gets below 0, it should be game over or win but it just skips and goes into negatives.

This is my code so far:

```
def Battle(E,H,S,PH):

  print('Battle starting')
  win = False
  while win == False:
    while True:
      Answer = input('Attack(\033[0;37;41mA\033[0;0;0m) or Defend(\033[0;37;41mA\033[0;0;0m)')
      if Answer == 'A':
        D = randint(0, S)
        PH = PH - D
        print(E,'attacking')
        print('deals',D,'damage')
        print('you now have',PH,'health')
        PA = randint(1,5)
        print('you deal',PA,'damage')
        H = H - PA
        print('the ',E,' has',H,'health')
        break
      elif A == 'D':
        D = randint(0, S-randint(0,2))
        PH = PH - D
        print( E,'atacking')
        print('deals',D,'damage')
        print('you now have',PH,'health')
        break
  if H <= 0:
    print('You killed the',E)
    win = True
    break
  elif PH <= 0:
    GameOver()
```

The bottom part is the bit that should exit and display text when you lose or win:

```
 if H <= 0:
        print('You killed the',E)
        win = True
        break
      elif PH <= 0:
        GameOver()
```

**Full Program**

```
#COPYRIGHT TYLER JAMES 2017 

import random
from random import randint

#_________________________________________________________________
#_________________________________________________________________
print('\033[0;0;0m')
print('\033[0;30;42m <><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>')
print('\033[0;30;42m <>                                                      <>')
print('\033[0;30;42m <> _        _______  _______  _______  _        ______  <>')
print('\033[0;30;42m <>( \      (  ____ \(  ____ \(  ____ \( (    /|(  __  \ <>')
print('\033[0;30;42m <>| (      | (    \/| (    \/| (    \/|  \  ( || (  \  )<>')
print('\033[0;30;42m <>| |      | (__    | |      | (__    |   \ | || |   ) |<>')
print('\033[0;30;42m <>| |      |  __)   | | ____ |  __)   | (\ \) || |   | |<>')
print('\033[0;30;42m <>| |      | (      | | \_  )| (      | | \   || |   ) |<>')
print('\033[0;30;42m <>| (____/\| (____/\| (___) || (____/\| )  \  || (__/OX)<>')
print('\033[0;30;42m <>(_______/(_______/(_______)(_______/|/    )_)(______/ <>')
print('\033[0;30;42m <>                                       By  Tyler James<>')
print('\033[0;30;42m <>                                                      <>')
print('\033[0;30;42m <><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>')
print('\033[0;0;0m have Fun playing this game,i worked hard to make it thanks')
print('___________________________________________________________')

#_________________________________________________________________
#_________________________________________________________________
#DEFINITION OF GAMEOVER
def GameOver():
  while True:
    print('GAME OVER')
#DEFINITION OF GAMEOVER

def Battle(E,H,S,PH):

  print('Battle starting')
  win = False
  while win == False:
    while True:
      Answer = input('Attack(\033[0;37;41mA\033[0;0;0m) or Defend(\033[0;37;41mD\033[0;0;0m)')
      if Answer == 'A':
        D = randint(0, S)
        PH = PH - D
        print(E,'attacking')
        print('deals',D,'damage')
        print('you now have',PH,'health')
        PA = randint(1,5)
        print('you deal',PA,'damage')
        H = H - PA
        print('the ',E,' has',H,'health')
        break
      elif A == 'D':
        D = randint(0, S-randint(0,2))
        PH = PH - D
        print( E,'atacking')
        print('deals',D,'damage')
        print('you now have',PH,'health')
        break

    if H <= 0:
      print('You killed the',E)
      win = True
      break
    elif PH <= 0:
      GameOver()



#DEFINITION OF QUIZ
def Quiz(Q,AN):
  print(Q)
  INP = input('Answer?')
  if INP == 'debug42':
    print('debug42')
  elif INP != AN:
    GameOver()
  else:
    print('CORRECT')
#DEFINITION OF QUIZ
#_________________________________________________________________
#_________________________________________________________________
#LEVEL 1
Name = input('What is your Name?')
print('Ok your name is','\033[0;37;41m',Name )
print('\033[0;0;0m')
print('You are in a small room with a door, opposite sits a dresser')
key = False
while True:
  A = input('What do you do?')
  if A == 'open door':
    if key == True:
      print('you try the key in the door')

      print('it works, you open the door and walk through')

      break
    elif key == False:
      print('The door wont open')
  elif A == 'look door':
    print('the door has a panel design and a keyhole on the right hand side')
  elif A == 'look dresser':
    print('their are two drawers')
  elif A == 'open dresser':
    print('there is nothing in the top drawer')

    print('but in the second is a brass key')
    key = True
  elif A == 'help':
    print('---------------------------------------------')
    print('Commands')
    print('open object...use object')
    print('look object...describe object')
    print('room...repeats the infomation given at start')
    print('COMMANDS NEED TO BE\033[1m \033[4mLOWERCASE\033[0m NEVER USE \033[1m\033[4mCAPS\033[0m')
    print('---------------------------------------------')  
  elif A == 'room':
    print('You are in a small room with a door, opposite sits a dresser')
  elif A == 'debug42':
    break
  else:
    print('\033[0;37;41m    Incorrect command or string', '\033[0;0;0m')
print('congrats you escaped the room')
#LEVEL 1
#_________________________________________________________________
#_________________________________________________________________
#LEVEL 2
print('____________________________________________')
print('A wise looking man walks up to you')
print('\033[1;33;40m"Here is 3 riddles get ONE wrong DIE!!"\033[0;0;0m')




Quiz('\033[1;33;40m"You will always find me in the past. I can be created in the present, But the future can never taint me. What am I?"\033[0;0;0m','history')


Quiz('\033[1;33;40m"Which vehicle is spelled the same forwards and backwards?"\033[0;0;0m','racecar')


Quiz('\033[1;33;40m"What is it that no man ever yet did see, which never was, but always is to be?"\033[0;0;0m','tomorrow')


print('\033[1;33;40m"Fine you can pass take these Jems, I wish you luck... If you ever make it out of this town "\033[0;0;0m')
print('\033[1;33;42m',Name,' got 5₪ (₪ = Ducat) \033[0;0;0m')
Money = 5
#LEVEL 2
#_________________________________________________________________
#_________________________________________________________________
#LEVEL 3
print('You enter a shop')
print('\033[1;33;40m"Welcome too my shop would you like to purchase a level 1 sword and sheild for 5₪?"\033[0;0;0m')
print('you have', Money,'₪')
print('you buy the item -5₪')
print('\033[1;33;42m',Name,'got a Sword[1] and Shield[1]')
print('you leave the shop')
print('_____________________________________________________')
Battle('Bat',10,5,50)
```

Comment: What error are you getting?  Generally the error will tell you what's going on.

Comment: it doesnt return an error it just doesnt activate the IF have a look

Comment: https://repl.it/FCtI/28

Comment: @Catmanj: I am good at programming and maths, and some people thought I may be autistic. Would you like to talk to me?

Comment: You know you write `'\033[1;33;40m"Welcome..."'` and things like that? It would help if you used a *library* that gave names to those sequences. Then other people could read your program.

Comment: How would i do that? make = a string including it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I moved the `if` to the top and now it works:

```
def Battle(E,H,S,PH):

  print('Battle starting')
  win = False
  while win == False:
    if H <= 0:
      print('You killed the',E)
      win = True
      break
    elif PH <= 0:
      GameOver()
    while True:
      Answer = input('Attack(\033[0;37;41mA\033[0;0;0m) or Defend(\033[0;37;41mD\033[0;0;0m)')
      if Answer == 'A':
        D = randint(0, S)
        PH = PH - D
        print(E,'attacking')
        print('deals',D,'damage')
        print('you now have',PH,'health')
        PA = randint(1,5)
        print('you deal',PA,'damage')
        H = H - PA
        print('the ',E,' has',H,'health')
        break
      elif A == 'D':
        D = randint(0, S-randint(0,2))
        PH = PH - D
        print( E,'atacking')
        print('deals',D,'damage')
        print('you now have',PH,'health')
        break
```

Comment: I quote your game: *NEVER USE CAPS*

Comment: yes, this works, but this is because you have increased the indentation. Try the full code again which you posted in the question. This one works too. You should move the if block down again

Answer (score 1):

the block starting with `if H <= 0` has the wrong indentation. It is currently outside the `while True` loop and hence never gets executed. You need to add 4 spaces to this block to move it within the `while True` loop:

```
if H <= 0:
  print('You killed the',E)
  win = True
  break
elif PH <= 0:
  GameOver()
```

and then it gets executed.

P.S. good thing starting with programming at age 13. Get that thing going!

Comment: I mean you can look at the entire code if u want https://repl.it/FCtI/28

Comment: that doesn't work because I have 2 while loops and your telling me to put it in the second one which keeps asking for INPUT

Comment: @Catmantj it's currently not in either loop.  Shouldn't it be in the first one?

Comment: i have put it in the correct place but it keep say Unreachable Code

Comment: I see that in the full code you posted you have changed the indentation so the `H <= 0` check is within the `while win == False` block. I've tried your full code and this version works

Answer (score 0):

are you missing a break statement after the GameOver() call ?

Comment: Well, from the code you linked the GameOver doesn't really quits. You get stack in a endless loop.